# Policy rewrite-uri To Append Context Variable in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, policy, azure-api-management

What is the approach to a simple append to the url of a context variable such as `context.Variables["accountKey"]` during a policy rewrite?

The end result should be `/accounts/232`.

I have success earlier in setting it

```
set-variable (0.003 ms)
{
    "message": "Context variable was successfully set.",
    "name": "accountKey",
    "value": "232"
}
```

One of the things tried:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <rewrite-uri template="/accounts/{accountKey}" />
    </inbound>
```

But I get this error

```
> Error Receive
>     rewrite-uri (0.260 ms) {
>     "messages": [
>         null,
>         "Variable accountKey has no value.",
>         "Variable accountKey has no value."
>     ] }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Configure the inbound rule in the policy as follows:

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-variable name="accountKey" value="232" />
    <rewrite-uri template="@{
        return "/account/" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("accountKey");
    }"/>
</inbound>
```

{} in rewrite-uri are for query string parameters in the original request URL.

Find more details about rewrite-uri section in the Microsoft docs at [Rewrite URL - API Management transformation policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL).

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using this call as shown as an alternative:

`<rewrite-uri template="@($"/account/{(string)context.Variables["accountKey"]}/")" />`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, my URL was

```
https://test.com/send/
```

I need to add query string from context variable name (name = `myName`)

```
https://test.com/send/myName
```

This is working for me:

```
<rewrite-uri template="@($"{(string)context.Variables["name"]}")" />
```